# How to create multiple users in azure b2c with graph api?

Tags: arrays, azure, jsonschema, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

As the title says I want to be able to take multiple users from a database and add them to my azure B2C tenant.  I have already successfully created single users using the B2C graph client.  I would also like to know if someone has created a json schema to help in user creation with the B2C graph client.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have successfully create user using B2C graph client , you could do the same way to send multi create user post request to create multiple users . For example , you could read users from database into datatable ,then loop the datatable ,initialize the user object inside and send create user request . For example ,  refer to [this code sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-GraphAPI-DotNet)  , you could try below code to create users:

```
private static void CreateUser()
{

    //here you need to loop datatable and assign values
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        UserData user = new UserData();
        user.accountEnabled = true;
        SignInName sn = new SignInName();
        sn.type = "emailAddress";
        sn.value = "nanyuTest"+i+"@nanyutestb2c.onmicrosoft.com";
        user.signInNames = new List<SignInName>();
        user.signInNames.Add(sn);
        user.creationType = "LocalAccount";
        user.displayName = "nan yu";
        user.mailNickname = "nanyuTest" + i;
        PasswordProfile pf = new PasswordProfile();
        pf.password = "P@ssword!";
        pf.forceChangePasswordNextLogin = false;
        user.passwordProfile = pf;
        user.passwordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
        object formatted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(client.CreateUser(json).Result);

        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(formatted, Formatting.Indented));
    }
}

    public class SignInName
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }

    public class PasswordProfile
    {
        public string password { get; set; }
        public bool forceChangePasswordNextLogin { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserData
    {
        public bool accountEnabled { get; set; }
        public List<SignInName> signInNames { get; set; }
        public string creationType { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string mailNickname { get; set; }
        public PasswordProfile passwordProfile { get; set; }
        public string passwordPolicies { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public object country { get; set; }
        public object facsimileTelephoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string givenName { get; set; }
        public object mail { get; set; }
        public object mobile { get; set; }           
        public string postalCode { get; set; }
        public object preferredLanguage { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public object streetAddress { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public object telephoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

Details on the optional fields of user entity ,you can be found in the [Azure AD Graph API entity reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity).

Comment: Where in the code sample would I place this code? Would I replace the current CreateUser() function?  I am not well versed in C#.   Would I still be using a json file to create users and if so would I need to make several json files or does this new function have the ability to read an array from the json?  Does this function require a different syntax from the old CreateUser() function?

Comment: In code sample , it read json string from file , with my code you could read data from database to a datatable( this part code you could search on internet) , then loop datatable and assign values to user entity and send create users(my above code) . In code sample , you could comment out below line which read json from file :   string json = File.ReadAllText(args[1]);

Comment: Any update ? please feel free to let me know if you have any problem.